# How to get the physical file name of running class library

Tags: c#, file, system.diagnostics

I'm trying to create a class library which will load different files depending on its physical file name.

i.e. if physical file name is called "test.dll" it will load its settings from "test.config", if the file is duplicated and renamed to "copy.dll" then it will load its settings from "copy.config"....

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess(); 
//doesn't work as I'm loading the dll's dynamically into a console application and calling their methods.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for something along the lines of the System.Reflection.Assembly class? the GetAssembly method will help or the GetCallingAssembly or GetExecutingAssembly

Comment: What .NET object are using the read the config from inside the DLL? Because if you are using the default ConfigurationManager is will only read the .exe.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string filePath = typeof(SomeAssemblyMemberType).Assembly.CodeBase;
```

[`CodeBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.codebase.aspx) property returns absolute path to the loaded manifest-containing file, or if assembly was loaded using `Load` method, returns path to assembly in which loader method is.

For example if you had the following code in a class object in your DLL:

```
public class Grace
{
    public Grace() {}

    public string AbsoluteFileName
    {
        get {
            return this.GetType().Assembly.CodeBase;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Assembly:

```
 string filePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location;
```

Comment: The will return path of the assembly that called the DLL.